# Is there any example for real project where field of deciamal type been used?

Tags: entities

Drupal has several types of numeric fields:

- integer
- float
- decimal

I know, that decimal field is used to store numeric data with high accuracy. But when it may be necessary in real project? Are there any good examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link to an explanation](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/decimal-float-or-integer-in-drupal-fields/) of Drupal's different number types (integer vs. decimal vs. float) with some examples. Basically, it breaks down as follows:

- **Integer:** You're storing numbers *without fractional digits* (e.g. a field that stores a product stock quantity, *XX units*)
- **Decimal:** You're storing numbers *with a **fixed amount** of fractional digits*. (e.g. a field that stores a price, *$XXX.YY*)
- **Float:** You're storing numbers *with a **variable amount** of fractional digits*. (e.g. a field that stores latitude/longitude coordinates, *XX.XXXXXXX..., YY.YYYYY...*)

Also of note is the underlying data structures of integer/decimal/float that gets stored in the database. See [Fixed point vs. Floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524838/fixed-point-vs-floating-point-number) for some discussion on the differences.